# use relations in controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-relations

Hi I want to implement this through relationships that show questions that the user of my site has registered answers and can see the questions in which he participated.
I dont know what should I do.
this is my controller

```
public function index(){

   $threads=Thread::with('answers')->where('user_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();

   return view('answer-question.thread.thread', compact('threads'));

}
```

Column `user_id` is in the answer table
and this is my view that i wanna use foreach (show the Threads that have the condition )
and i have one to many relation between Thread and Answer

```
   @foreach($thread as $thread)
   <dive>..........</dive>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: You will need to show the relationships between `Thread`, `Answer`, and `User` models.

Answer (score 0):

If i understandood this, do you need something like this:

```
$threads=Thread::with('answers')->where('answers.user_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: sir i doesnt work.

Answer (score -1):

**You should do it like this:**

```
$threads=Thread::with(['answers'=>function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id',auth()->id());
        })
    ])->get();
```

Comment: thanks sir    but it doesnt working I tried.  do you have another idea?

Comment: What kind of relationship are you using?
One To One,
One To Many,
One To Many (Inverse) / Belongs To,
Has One Of Many,
Has One Through,
Has Many Through,